# Extending abelian groups to rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, abelian-groups

I've been reading this article about extending abelian groups to rings: http://www.math.udel.edu/~coulter/papers/rings.pdf.

Could you explain to me why theorem 2.1 guarantees left and right distribution?

PS. Could you also tell me if I understand the whole thing correctly?
We take any function $f: G \rightarrow G$, then define multiplication by $*_f$ and then prove that $(G, +, *_f)$ is indeed a ring, is that right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left distributivity: $x \star (y+z) = f(x + (y + z)) - f(x) - f(y + z) = f(x+y) + f(x+z) + f(y+z) - f(x) - f(y) - f(z) - f(x) - f(y+z) = f(x+y) + f(x+z) -2f(x) -f(y) - f(z) = (f(x+y) - f(x) - f(y)) + (f(x+z)-f(x)-f(z)) = x \star y + x \star z$

Right distributivity then follows from commutativity of $\star$, for $(x+y)\star z = z\star(x+y) = z\star x + z\star y = x \star z + y\star z$.