# How do I find a functor from the category $\mathbf{Ab}$ to $\mathbf{Rng}$?

Tags: category-theory

I don't think just mapping any abelian group to a ring with this same underlying abelian groups will do. There's the issue of the ring being not necessarily unique. What other way is there which works?

Comment: Group ring functor.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: I haven't seen this, and I looked around but couldn't find this example worked out somewhere.

Comment: Given the attempt, are you specifically looking for an adjoint of the forgetful functor?

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354884/extending-abelian-groups-to-rings, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130390/

Comment: Another way: ring with zero multiplication

Comment: If you are just looking for **a** functor, you can take your favorite ring $R$ and send every abelian groups to $R$ and every abelian group morphisms to $\mathrm{id}_R$. Of course, this functor is not very interesting... I guess my point is that your post lacks some context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to turn an abelian group into a ring, but the simplest and natural one is to take the zero multiplication. That is, having an abelian group $A$ define multiplication on it as $$\forall x,y \in A: \, x\cdot y = 0$$

This makes an rng from an abelian group. To make this into an actual functor, we should specify how it acts on morphisms. Let's just map all homomorphisms in $\operatorname{Ab}$ into the same functions, which appear to be rng homomorphisms, thanks to zero multiplication:

$$f(x\cdot y)=f(0)=0=f(x)\cdot f(y)$$

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.